# Django Rest Framework & Angular Dev vs Prod string & byte issue on json.loads()

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

On releasing my site to staging server certain server calls have stopped working. They now need to be decoded utf-8.

Backend is running Django Rest Framework, Frontend is Angular 9.

I can't see why two similar setups on two different machines is causing such a random issue.

Headers include settings the charset to utf-8 (below)

`headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');`

But this doesn't effect the dev server.

Does anyone have any experience in this issue?

Comment: Do you send the data through `request.body`?

Comment: Yup, using HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't know why this is happening but using the below work around.

```
if isinstance(request.body,bytes):
    resp2 = json.loads(request.body.decode("uft-8"))
if isinstance(request.body,str):
    resp2 = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: using `json.loads(request.body)` not work?, python3.6+ `json.loads` also support `bytes`

Comment: No, kept falling over, I originally used just `json.loads(request.body)`